# How to make report printing with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, report, reporting, zend-pdf

I using `Zend.1.7.2` in my project and i need report printing like `Crystal report` in 
`C# or VB.net`. In first time I want it with function `zend-pdf` but i can't success with it. 
so anyone can point me with a way that can print data out. 
Note: my data is get from database.
Any help please, I am looking to see your reply soon.
Thanks

Comment: you could try [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en)

Comment: I am note that I can't find code of it. yes it's look like interest if i can do like this :)

Comment: you can download on sourceforge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phphtml2pdf/files/release/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something where you can design your report and fill it with information later, you can use PHPJasperXML which is an implementation of Jasper Reports on PHP, it exports to PDF and Excel and you can get it from here: http://www.simit.com.my/?q=PHPJasperXML